# NP-completeness of the exact distance problem

Tags: np-complete, np, hamiltonian-path

I am currently learning about NP-complete problems and I want to make sure my understanding is correct.

Here is a problem I am working on currently:

> The exact distance problem is, given an edge-weighted graph $G = (V,E)$, vertices $v_1,v_k$, and a distance $D$, is there a simple path from $v_1$ to $v_k$ with length exactly $D$?

The first part of my solution is proving that the problem is in NP. I did this by picking a solution to the problem and proving that we can verify the solution in polynomial time. My proof showed that we can verify the solution in $O(mn)$ time, where $m$ is the number of edges and $n$ is the number of vertices.

The next part is showing that a problem we know to be NP-complete can be reduced to the exact distance problem. I am having trouble deciding on an easy NP-Complete problem to use in this part. Would the Hamiltonian Path problem be a good choice?

Comment: Hamiltonian cycle sounds as the one

Comment: If you're having trouble, why not try your suggestion out?

Comment: As I said in the question, I wanted to make sure my understanding of how to solve the problem was correct.

Comment: Yuval's suggestion isn't flippant, it's the best way to get better at this type of problem.  There's no mechanical way to know ahead of time whether some particular NP-hard problem will turn out to be a good source problem for this kind of proof; all you can do is build experience by trying some out, which gradually improves your intuition.  (It's also necessary to see some good worked examples, and to *make sure you understand* what each step does and why it's needed.  This can involve spending many hours on a few lines!  But don't worry, your speed will improve.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. ​ Keep in mind *exactly* what the inputs to each problem are.

Comment: How does this sound for the proof: An instance of the Hamiltonian Path problem is a Graph G and vertices v1 and vn. Form a new graph G' by assigning weights to each edge such that the sum of the weighted edges from v1 to vn is equal to a distance D. Graph G has a Hamiltonian path if and only if grapg G' has a simple path from v1 to vn with length exactly D. Since G' can be computed in polynomial time, this is a polynomial time reduction.

Comment: That's not the usual definition "of the Hamiltonian Path problem". ​ ​ ​ If that's your class's definition, then my answer's ​ "You'll ... path." ​ sentence does not apply. ​ ​ ​ What are "the weighted edges from v1 to vn"? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: What I did was take an instance from the Hamiltonian path problem and showed that we can create an instance of the exact distance problem in polynomial time. The first part isn't necessarily stating the definition of a Hamiltonian Path, but rather showing an instance of a solution (if that makes sense). From there, we can construct an instance of the Exact Distance problem by assigning weights to each edge along the Hamiltonian Path such that the weighted edges equal a distance D. Thus, we have created an instance of the exact distance problem. Does that make sense?

Comment: Under the usual definition, what you "did was take an instance from the Hamiltonian path problem" _and something else_. ​ An instance of the problem is _all_ the reduction gets, so unless you've shown P=NP, it doesn't necessarily know what edges are "along the Hamiltonian path". ​ However, I now realize that, even under the standard definition, there's no need to go back to the proof - One can just use the hardness result itself, so I've edited my answer. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Mike: "Form a new graph G' by assigning weights to each edge such that the sum of the weighted edges from v1 to vn is equal to a distance D."  It's not clear whether you intend (a) the edges of G' to be the same as those in G, but with specific weights (this makes sense insofar as the input you're building is then at least related to the original HP instance G, but then it's not clear that assigning these weights can be done at all, let alone in polynomial time) or (b) to create a specific new set of edges for G' (in which case how is the resulting instance related to G at all?).